# CDIR= $(pwd) gives "Permission denied"

Tags: scripts

I have a very simple shell script, called deploy.sh

```
#!/bin/sh 

CDIR= $(pwd)
echo Hello World!
```

Unfortunately, running it gives the following error:

```
bird@bird-laptop:~/foo$ sh deploy.sh 
deploy.sh: 3: deploy.sh: /home/bird/foo: Permission denied
Hello World!
```

Any clues, why this is happening?

```
bird@bird-laptop:~/foo$ ls -l
total 156
-rwxrwxrwx 1 bird bird   327 April  18 00:57 deploy.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 bird bird   327 April  18 00:53 deploy.sh~
```

Comment: Give [SpellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/) a try for simple errors.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remove the space character after the `=` in

```
CDIR= $(pwd)
```

`sh` doesn't allow any spaces around the `=`.

`CDIR= $(pwd)` means "*Run the output of `pwd` with the variable `CDIR` unset.*"

As you can't run a folder you get `Permission denied`.

Answer (score 5):

```
CDIR= $(pwd)
# ...^
```

You must not have spaces around the `=` in an assignment.

What this is doing: `var=value command` is a legal statement. It sets the "var" variable in the environment of the "command", but only in that environment. For your command, the shell sees this:

```
CDIR= $(pwd)           # first, process the $()
CDIR= /home/bird/foo   # prepare the env with CDIR="" and execute /home/bird/foo
                       # oops, cannot execute /home/bird/foo
```

Answer (score 3):

When you [assign a value to a variable](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/varassignment.html) in `sh` (or other shell scripting language), never use any space before and after equal:

```bsh
CDIR= $(pwd)
CDIR=$(pwd)
```

Here is a quote from the given link:

> =
>
> the assignment operator (*no space before and after*)

Comment: Quoting doesn't harm, but `$()` already returns a single token, ie. no quoting is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Florian is correct, but you're still missing an update

```
#!/bin/sh 

CDIR=$(pwd)
echo $CDIR
echo Hello World!
```

After the value is assigned it must be converted to a string, as you cannot inline a command directly to a variable for display.  See [here](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-5.html).

Comment: Then I shall retract my comment and edit the post.